# circular flat uv issue

Tags: uv

I am trying to unwrap this flat ring shape, I know I can follow active quads to change the unwrap from circular to a strip, but my question is why blender do not unwrap this shape as a strip when placing the seam? Am I doing anything wrong?

What I get..
[image: what i get]

What I want..
[image: what i want]

Many Thanks.

Comment: Hey :). I'd say the standard unwrap tries to keep the face size and shape. That's why it still looks like a ring.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Just wishing Blender UV's would get some more love an attention from the developers.

Comment: Feel free to suggest improvements on [rightclickselect](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/) :)

Answer (score 1):

you will lose texel density if you Unfold it like what you want and blender is unfolding in true way - if you want to unfold as a line and it be straight - use addon Textools > Rectify [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not just texel density.  The bigger issue is UV distortion.  Mapping trapezoid faces onto rectangles is going to give you UV mapping where you have 2D/3D disagreement that depends on triangulation.

Comment: Yeah true.but It really depends on you and your method of texturing to what kind of UV you need :)

Comment: Which, Blender doesn't know.  Hence, it's decision to prefer to minimize UV distortion over anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at two different texture bakes, to two different styles of UV maps.

[image]

Top left is a purely procedural image, where I use an RGB curves node to make a line on the basis of the length of object coords.

Top middle is that procedural texture, baked to an unwrap.

Top right is that procedural texture, baked to a follow-active quads unwrap.

Middle bottom is, honestly, the same as top right.  It is the same mesh, with a triangulate modifier on "fixed" mode-- the same mode which is used by Blender for default triangulation.  It looks exactly like top right.

Other than due to sampling, *all four of these circles are identical.*  The fifth is not:

Right bottom is a triangulated version of Top Right, but using "Fixed Alternate" triangulation.  Why is everything suddenly so wonky?  Because you're using triangulated trapezoids that are mapped onto UV rectangles, and the trapezoids aren't triangulated in the way intended by the bake.

What else will create the fifth picture?  Making a straight line in photoshop and then mapping it onto any of the follow-active-quads mappings.  Failing to export a triangulated mesh and trying to paint a Blender quad mesh in Substance Painter.  What will work?  Making a circle in photoshop and mapping it onto the unwrap.  Painting in SP on the unwrap, even if you fail to triangulate.

So unwrapping to prioritize the minimization of distortion allows people to use Photoshop to create textures, it allows them to use Substance Painter to make textures without pre-triangulating their mesh.

Sorry for the small images.  Imgur suddenly doesn't like 4k.

Answer (score 1):

Select a single face, <kbd>U</kbd> Unwrap, make the texture region rectangular in whatever way you find the most logical (I'm dragging opposite corners on Y axis with vertex snapping enabled). Now select whole ring, and <kbd>U</kbd> Follow Active Quads.

[image]